# Source Control for SQL Server Management Studio 2019

Tags: git, version-control, ssms

Any idea how to add the source control option under tools to Sql server management studio 2019. [SSMS Source control option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB44g.png)

I came across a post that advises to edit the ssms.pkgundef file but this is not relevant to SSMS 2019.

Comment: *"I  came across a post that advises to edit the ssms.pkgundef file but this is not relevant to SSMS 2019."* What do you mean by this? SSMS **19** (there's no such thing as SSMS 2019) has an SSMS.pkgundef file.